# call function through reference (?)

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have the following function call (myFunc() is of type double):

```
double value = F1->F2->myFunc();
```

I would like to get something that when i call value it should call F1->F2->myFunc();

With the help of the forum I got help and understood than calling a function through a variable i should do something like:

```
typedef double(*)() m;
m variable = myFunc;
```

and call it like variable();

Unfortunatly with the above setup it doesn't really work,
I get a reference to &F2::myFunc but how do i get it in the above setup?

something like:

```
typedef double(*)() m;
m variable = &F2::myFunc; <- doesn't work :(
```

Thank you guys for any Help!

Comment: Look up member function pointers, `std::bind`, `std::function` and Lambdas - with an understanding of these, you'll know what to do and why your code "doesn't work"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
std::function<double()> variable = std::bind(&ClassOfF2::myFunc, F1->F2);

double value = variable();
```

Comment: Why use bind if you can use Lambdas?

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to get something that when i call value it should call F1->F2->myFunc();

In C++11, you could use a lambda:

```
auto l = [&] () { return F1->F2->myFunc(); };
double value = l();
```

[Scott Meyer's update](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.cz/2013/01/effective-c11-content-and-status.html) on his upcoming book Effective C++ 11 also mentions:

> Prefer lambdas to `std::bind`.